# can't access cmake variable defined inside function using PARENT_SCOPE

Tags: cmake, cmake-scopes

So I have the following CMake code:

```
function(get_sources output_var)
    set(${output_var} "a" PARENT_SCOPE)
    message(${output_var}) # prints "SOURCES" (as expected)
    message(${${output_var}}) # throws an error - why?
    ...
endfunction(get_sources)

get_sources(SOURCES)
message(${SOURCES}) # prints "a" - ok, so the above function created a var
```

The `get_sources` function is supposed to create a variable with given name in parent scope and fill it with some content.

It seems like `get_sources(SOURCES)` creates the variable as expected - `message(${SOURCES})` outside function prints "a", but there's a problem with the line `message(${${output_var}})`. It should evaluate to `message(a)` and print "a", but instead it throws an error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:41 (message):
    message called with incorrect number of arguments
```

I am confused. Is it supposed to be like that? Should I make a function scoped variable, fill it in and then at the end copy its contents to a parent scope variable? I checked it - it works, but I wanted it to be without any additional variables.

**EDIT**:
I enclosed a `${${output_var}}` in quotation marks and now it doesn't throw an error, but it prints nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*PARENT_SCOPE* sets variable only for parent scope, not for the current one. This is explicitely stated in [CMake documentation about 'set' command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/set.html):

> If the *PARENT_SCOPE* option is given the variable will be set in the scope above the current scope. Each new directory or function creates a new scope. This command will set the value of a variable into the parent directory or calling function (whichever is applicable to the case at hand). **The previous state of the variable’s value stays the same in the current scope** (e.g., if it was undefined before, it is still undefined and if it had a value, it is still that value).

This is a proper way for handle PARENT_SCOPE variables:

> Should I make a function scoped variable, fill it in and then at the end copy its contents to a parent scope variable?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was reading the older documentation which doesn't include the bold text :)